# Flutter - Building a custom counter widget for a text field - Cannot get currentLength

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a [custom counter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/buildCounter.html) for a textfield in flutter. However, I don't know how to get the current length of my textField, as I don't know how to get the value. Also I'm using [reactive_forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms) for my textfield.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';

class VpTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const VpTextFormField(this.formControlName, this.hintText,
      {this.maxLength,
      this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
      this.validationMessages});

  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final String formControlName;
  final String hintText;
  final int maxLength;
  final Map<String, String> Function(AbstractControl<dynamic>)
      validationMessages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReactiveTextField(
        formControlName: formControlName,
        validationMessages: validationMessages,
        maxLength: maxLength,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: hintText,
            counter: counter(context, maxLength: maxLength, currentLength: ?????)), // need to find a way to get the current length
        textAlign: textAlign);
  }
}

Widget counter(
  BuildContext context, {
  int currentLength,
  int maxLength,
  bool isFocused,
}) {
  return Text(
    '$currentLength of $maxLength characters',
    semanticsLabel: 'character count',
  );
}
```

In my view:

```
VpTextFormField(
                      'nickname',
                      'Nickname...',
                      validationMessages: (control) => {
                        'required': 'Please enter your name / alter ego'
                      },
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLength: 20,
                    ),
```

In my controller:

```
  final form = FormGroup({
    'nickname': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
  });
```

How can I get the currentLength of my textField to pass it to my custom counter?

Answer (score 1):

Well I made it work in the end by changing my code to this, but it made the validation messages not display which is a major fail. I don't think it is a bug in my code that caused that, something might be wrong with `buildCounter` in general. Pretty gutted.

Anyway, working code, but removes validation message:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';

class VpTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const VpTextFormField(this.formControlName, this.hintText,
      {this.maxLength,
      this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
      this.validationMessages});

  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final String formControlName;
  final String hintText;
  final int maxLength;
  final Map<String, String> Function(AbstractControl<dynamic>)
      validationMessages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReactiveTextField(
        formControlName: formControlName,
        validationMessages: validationMessages,
        maxLength: maxLength,
        buildCounter: counter(context,
            currentLength: 0, isFocused: false, maxLength: maxLength),
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: hintText),
        textAlign: textAlign);
  }
}

Widget Function(BuildContext,
    {int currentLength, bool isFocused, int maxLength}) counter(
  BuildContext context, {
  int currentLength,
  bool isFocused,
  int maxLength,
}) {
  return (context, {currentLength, isFocused, maxLength}) => Container(
      child: Text(
        '$currentLength of $maxLength characters',
        semanticsLabel: 'character count',
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight);
}
```

Comment: Same thing happening to me, the validation message disappears when I use buildCounter. It's extremely annoying. Have you ever gotten around this?

Comment: @Josenaldo I removed `buildCounter` and `counter` from the TextField, put the TextField in a Stack, and added my own custom counter widget over the top of the TextField in the top right corner. I used `field.value.length` in `reactive_forms` to get the number in the counter, but you can get the length in other ways, such as the `TextEditingController.text.length`.